# unknown directive "passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process"

Tags: node.js, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to write a web backend using Node.js, Passenger, and nginx.
It was working great until I tried to add multiple node processes using the `passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process` setting. For some reason adding that setting gives me the following error:
`unknown directive "passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process"`

If I comment that line out it works fine, so I really don't know what's going on. Any help would be welcome.

Thanks,
-tlf

### EDIT:

nginx and Passenger both work perfectly until I try to change that setting, at which point nginx fails to start due to the aforementioned error. If I remove that line, everything works normally again.

And yes, I do know exactly what that line of code does, which is why I'm trying to add it in the first place. I would really appreciate being able to set that property, but I am unable to because it's crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely possibility is that your Passenger version is too old. passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process was introduced in version 5.0.22.

The other possibility is that you did not update your Nginx installation when upgrading Passenger.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it. Turns out I'm running 5.0.21. Now the problem is how do I update it? Running `brew upgrade nginx --with-passenger` doesn't work because nginx is up to date, and `brew reinstall nginx --with-passenger` just reinstalls v5.0.21.

Comment: The [official Passenger documentation website](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library) has [instructions on upgrading Passenger with Homebrew](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/upgrade/oss/#osx).

Comment: yeah, but those instructions didn't work. They just reinstalled 5.0.21. I'll keep looking, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: But did you run *both* commands? You need to run `brew upgrade passenger nginx --with-passenger` *first*, and (only if no new Nginx version has been released) *also* run `brew reinstall nginx --with-passenger`

Comment: Found the problem! I had to run `brew update` first to update the local caches. After I did that, everything was able to update perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**You have made it comment out that means it is made 0.**

There are two main use cases for this option:

1. To make [dynamic process scaling](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/dynamic_scaling_vs_fixed_app_processes/) work in Node.js and Meteor
   applications. Set this option to approximately the number of
   concurrent requests at which the performance of a single process
   begins to degrade.
2. [To make SSE and WebSockets work well in Ruby applications](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/tuning_sse_and_websockets/). Set this
   option to 0.

Resource Link:

1. [passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process)
2. [Dynamic scaling of Node.js application processes vs fixed process
   pool](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/dynamic_scaling_vs_fixed_app_processes/nodejs/)

### UPDATE1:

`passenger_start_timeout` specifies a timeout for the startup of application processes. **If an application process fails to start within the timeout period then it will be forcefully killed with SIGKILL, and the error will be logged**.

Comment: I know what it does, and I know what happens when it is set to 0. My question was why is it crashing when its **not** commented out? I'm _trying_ to enable dynamic scaling, but I can't start nginx because it's giving me an `unknown directive` error.

Comment: @thislooksfun I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully it makes the problem I'm having more clear.